# Suspect Interpol Case

Tags: international-law, uae

I was working in Kuwait for last seven years..had left from there due to some managerial issues. I dont have any loan or debt outstanding in Kuwait. But i have been informed by a friend of mine that due to internal politics company had filed a case with INTERPOL against me. Please can i get advise how this will affect me in future. If i travel to other GCC counties or for any international travel i will be blocked ? What will be their intention to file case against me with INTERPOL. I dont have any case against me in Kuwait. Is there any chance to check the case details that exists..

Please share the experience.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can Interpol be involved without a local police case? I thought it was just a system for networking among national law enforcement organizations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have done some serious crimes to be flagged by interpol. I don't think that is the case. If at all a case was filed, it might be with the local police. However, this could affect you if you are immigrating to another country because you would have to provide a police clearance certificate from all the countries that you have stayed in previously for a period of more than 3 months. If there is a case filed against you, then that might affect your immigration. Depends on the severity of the crime however, and for a financial issue, again, I don't think that could also be a problem. You can check if your name is on interpol by doing a search [here](https://www.interpol.int/notice/search/wanted). Inform me with a comment if you do. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The only request you would raise on INTERPOL is an international arrest warrant. It is not trivial to get this, first:

1. Your employer has to file a case against you.
2. The case has to be of criminal nature.
3. A court must decide if a warrant is necessary.
4. A local warrant is issued first.
5. Based on the request of the ministry of interior, a request for an international warrant is raised.
6. INTERPOL reviews the request and issues an international notice.

They don't do this for cases such as absconding (typically this is the case filed) or breach of trust (another common case against staff).

So, first of all - find out what exactly is going on against you with the local ministry of interior. Unfortunately you can only do this if you still have a valid Civil ID, which if you have left the country you would not.

Next step is to ask someone (like a lawyer) to enquire on your behalf with your passport information if there are any outstanding warrants on you.  This is usually done at the Ministry of Justice. A competent lawyer can get this done within a day or two.

Next, you will need to find out the case details - again, you need a lawyer for this as this information is not released to relatives or friends.

Once you have this case information - you will know if indeed INTERPOL has been informed or its just rumors floating around.

If it is a simple case the lawyer may be able to settle it without your visit to Kuwait.

Comment: This sound like good information. Do you have an links to supporting information?

Comment: No, my only link is that for the past 12+ years, I am living in Kuwait as an expat.